# Create column with top and bottom values of other columns

Tags: r

Say my dataset has two columns

```
A = c(5,1,NA,NA,NA)

B = c(NA,NA,10,11,13)
```

How do I create a new column C that takes the bottom non-NA value from A and the top non-NA value from B to create a new column:

```
C= c(NA,1,10,NA,NA)
```

?

I asked a similar question earlier and got a great answer - applied it, and realized I'd asked the wrong question. Thanks for your help (again).

Comment: I do not understand. What's the logic? Please elaborate.

Comment: What would you expect if the data was `A = c(5,1,NA,NA,NA)` and `B = c(NA,10,11,12,13)`?

Comment: I'm creating a plot that has several different lines corresponding to separate subjects (indicated by different shades of blue in periods A and B). Period C is between A and B and the lines need to change to grey.  (Periods are same for all subjects and don't overlap.) My approach is to create different columns for each of these periods to call as the y value in geom_line so that I can assign a different colur to it. The code here is to take the last observation from the last period (column A) and the first observation from the next period (column B) to create a line that connects the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dplyr::coalesce` with `match` and `head`/`tail`:

```
dplyr::coalesce(
  A[match(A, tail(A[!is.na(A)], 1)) == 1],
  B[match(B, head(B[!is.na(B)], 1)) == 1]
)

# [1] NA  1 10 NA NA
```

Like others I am concerned with the logic and special cases, though this may save you in some of them (ie, if `A` or `B` had all `NA` values. In the case the @Phil mentioned (`B = c(NA,10,11,12,13)`, it will take it from whichever one is listed first (here, `A`)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)

A = c(5,1,NA,NA,NA)

B = c(NA,NA,10,11,13)

mydf <- data.frame(A = A, B = B)

mutate(mydf, C = case_when(A == last(A[!is.na(A)]) ~ A,
                           B == first(B[!is.na(B)]) ~ B))

   A  B  C
1  5 NA NA
2  1 NA  1
3 NA 10 10
4 NA 11 NA
5 NA 13 NA
```

But I don't feel this is safe, unless you are absolutely sure you won't see data that will break this code.

(Actually the use of `case_when()` will not break the code, as the subsequent line(s) would just be ignored because of the way that function operates. But it may not return what you'd expect silently, which if anything makes it more dangerous.)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I wanted as I am absolutely sure there's no data that would break it.